# Redux don't render the content of store

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to render the store's value on view, but it don't render. I don't know why it is not rendering. Can someone explain me why ? (I have watched Dan Abramov's course on Egg Head and I still not understanding)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { createStore } from 'redux';

const reducer = (state = 0, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      console.log('Increment', state);

      return ++state;

    case 'DECREMENT':
      console.log('Decrement', state);

      return --state;

    default:
      return state;
  }
} 

const store = createStore(
  reducer
)

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{JSON.stringify(this.props.store)}</p>

        <button onClick={() => store.dispatch({type: 'INCREMENT'})}>+</button>

        <button onClick={() => store.dispatch({type: 'DECREMENT'})}>-</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App store={store} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { createStore } from 'redux';

const reducer = (state = 0, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      console.log('Increment', state);

      return ++state;

    case 'DECREMENT':
      console.log('Decrement', state);

      return --state;

    default:
      return state;
  }
} 

const store = createStore(
  reducer
);

class App extends Component {
  update() {
      this.forceUpdate();
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.unsubscribe = store.subscribe(this.update.bind(this));
  }
  componentWillUnmount(){
      this.unsubscribe();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{JSON.stringify(store.getState())}</p>

        <button onClick={() => store.dispatch({type: 'INCREMENT'})}>+</button>

        <button onClick={() => store.dispatch({type: 'DECREMENT'})}>-</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Redux Connect to access state in component

ex:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(yourComponent);
```

Comment: I had try it (and `Provider`) before, but it don't work.

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';

import reducers from './reducers';
const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)// not needed
);
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>  
      <App/> 
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

App component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../actions';

class Signout extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.data);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Sorry to see you go</div>;
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { data: state.data};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(App);
```

Comment: you need to use comibeReducer like 

export default combineReducers({
  data: dataReducer
});

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't mutate the state directly. Instead do like this:

```
return state + 1; // instead of ++state
return state - 1; // instead of --state
```

To render the state:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{store.getState()}</p>
```

To get the changes of the store, you will also need to subscribe for the changes:

```
const unsubscribe = store.subscribe( // generally, this is called on event handler
  ReactDOM.render(
    <App store={store} />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  )
)
unsubscribe()
```

You may also subscribe the changes in componentDidMount and unsubscribe in the componentWillUnmount lifecycle hook. You may look at the answer provided by henok tesfaye: [subscribing and unsubscribing in lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52669432/2138752).

You can read it from the [docs](https://redux.js.org/api/store) to know more about it.

---

But in general, we don't need subscriber. We can get the changes through mapping the states using connect. This [blog](https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2017/03/31/react-redux-connect-explained/) explains it very well. So, I would suggest you to look at [Usage with react](https://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact)